# req.body.caption return null

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have this code which send what the active user publish into mongodb `id of the post + author + author ID + caption(what the author write)`, the code works perfectly but the problem that this statement`caption : req.body.caption,`is keep returning `null` to mongodb and I really don't know why or how to solve this,

the code of publish is below :

```
router.post("/publish", function (req, res, next) {
    // Generate a random id

    User.findById(req.user.id, function (err, user) {
        if (!user) {
            req.flash('error', 'No account found');
            return res.redirect('/login');
          } else {

          }

          user.posts.push({
            _id: guid.raw(),
            author: user.userName,
            authorID: user.id,
            caption : req.body.caption,
            comments: [],
            likes: [],
            createdAt: new Date(),
            lastEditedAt: new Date()
          });
          user.save(err => {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log("Post saved");

            res.redirect("/");
          });
    });
});
```

the schema of caption is below :

```
caption :{type : String}
```

the ejs part is also below

```
  <input
      type="text"
      id="caption"
      name="caption"
      class="form-control"
      placeholder="enter your posts"
      value="Share your thoughts!"
    />
```

[MongoDB screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rPGmv.png)

Please some help,

Best Regards,

Comment: Can you ```console.log(req.body.caption)``` and tell what's the value?

Comment: Maybe even log `req.body`? It seems likely the input control named `caption` is not included in the form post. You can also use the Network tab of your browser's devtools to examine the POST request.

Comment: it returns undefined but .... ! that so confusing

Comment: `console.log(req.body) => return this {}` and `console.log(req.body.caption) => returns undefined`

Comment: @O.Jones I posted my result above and also I checked the caption is included in the post form :-(

Comment: This shows that your form in EJS is not sending caption in the POST request body.
Check your code again for something you may have missed.

Comment: @RamarajaRamanujan and @O.Jones I did the provided solution and also I redo the whole ejs thing but nothing same result If I do `caption : user.userName => then in mongodb i found a result ` but if I do `caption : req.body.userName => mongodb Null` my EJS code is working  but here it is https://ibb.co/s5FLfVv

Comment: What error do you get now after your changes?

Comment: No error but it's keeps returning undefined and null ....  the problem that my anything I do with the `req.body.xxxx` doesn't return any values only null or undefined and I did everything changing entire EJS code and updating my code something ,,,,,,

Answer (score 2):

Your output from `console.log(req.body)` -- an empty `body` object -- proves beyond any doubt that no form fields are arriving at your route handler in your post.

It's possible you need to tell express to use a couple of middleware modules to parse the data in the bodies of POST requests. Try putting these two lines in your code somewhere before your call(s) to `app.use('/', router)`.

```
app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
```

These will make express populate the `req.body` object with the data from your forms. It chooses JSON or url-encoding based on the `Content-Type:` header.

Or it's possible your html (ejs) doesn't have your `<input...>` fields wrapped in your `<form....>` object.  You can tell if this is true by looking at your POST request in the Network tab of your browser. You'll find a section called Form Data if you click on the POST request. If it's empty, your form post sent nothing. If the `caption` field is empty, that field wasn't wrapped in the `<form ...>` tag.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, in the `app.js ` part I already have the `app.use('/',....) and alsie urlencoded part` and I also revized the ejs part  and it's included and also verified the POST request network and it's not emty but the caption is empty .. the ejs code is here https://ibb.co/nfxfch5

Comment: I think I will redo the ejs part step by step because on the console network I noticed this `HTML1509: The end tag is not consistent.` and it is referring to publish.ejs line  252,3 and 251,6 which contain the end of `</div> and </form>` see image https://ibb.co/b28kVnK